# Least GC consuming way to convert double to String without E and 10 digit precision

Tags: java, apache-spark, garbage-collection

My spark job is creating a lot of small  objects and running into Garbage Collection issue. I have tried multiple ways to convert double into String with 10 digit precision without Scientific notation.

First Way

```
String.format("%.10f", denomValue)
```

Error for this Case :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at sun.misc.FormattedFloatingDecimal.create(FormattedFloatingDecimal.java:254)
at sun.misc.FormattedFloatingDecimal.fillDecimal(FormattedFloatingDecimal.java:267)
at sun.misc.FormattedFloatingDecimal.<init>(FormattedFloatingDecimal.java:76)
at sun.misc.FormattedFloatingDecimal.valueOf(FormattedFloatingDecimal.java:38)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:3298)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:3238)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2802)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2925)
```

Second Way

```
new BigDecimal(d).setScale(10,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP).toPlainString()
```

Error for this case :-

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.math.MutableBigInteger.divideMagnitude(MutableBigInteger.java:1489)
at java.math.MutableBigInteger.divideKnuth(MutableBigInteger.java:1227)
at java.math.MutableBigInteger.divide(MutableBigInteger.java:1153)
at java.math.MutableBigInteger.divide(MutableBigInteger.java:1147)
at java.math.BigDecimal.divideAndRound(BigDecimal.java:4326)
at java.math.BigDecimal.setScale(BigDecimal.java:2470)
```

Comment: i wouldn't imagine the conversion itself is exhausting memory - it's more likely that holding on to a bunch of the source and converted values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting "[Understand the OutOfMemoryError Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html#sthref40)":

> **Exception in thread thread_name: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC Overhead limit exceeded**
>
> *Cause:* The detail message "GC overhead limit exceeded" indicates that the garbage collector is running all the time and Java program is making very slow progress. After a garbage collection, if the Java process is spending more than approximately 98% of its time doing garbage collection and if it is recovering less than 2% of the heap and has been doing so far the last 5 (compile time constant) consecutive garbage collections, then a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is thrown. This exception is typically thrown because the amount of live data barely fits into the Java heap having little free space for new allocations.
>
> *Action:* Increase the heap size. The java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception for GC Overhead limit exceeded can be turned off with the command line flag -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit.

If your code is truly spending 98% of its time doing garbage collection, then you should definitely increase the heap size, because it means that 98% of your memory is used for (semi-)permanent data, and less than 2% is free for temporary allocations.

*You may have serious memory leak issues.*

But as it says, you can disable that particular error, if needed.

As for your code, you should stick with option 1. Option 2 will create more garbage that option 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have benchmarked few opinions to format decimal number

- java.util.Formatter
- java.lang.String.format()
- java.text.DecimalFormat
- org.apache.xmlgraphics.util.DoubleFormatUtil.formatDouble()

In all cases I have measured memory wasted to format one decimal number.
Below are results for 32 JVM.

```
java.util.Formatter
Format mem usage: 1120
Format + string mem usage: 1184

java.text.DecimalFormat
Format + string mem usage: 288

org.apache.xmlgraphics.util.DoubleFormatUtil.formatDouble()
Format mem usage: 0
Format + string mem usage: 64

java.lang.String.format()
Format + string mem usage: 1448
```

Code is below

```
@Test
public void testDecimalFormat() {
    double pi = Math.PI;
    System.out.println("\njava.text.DecimalFormat");

    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat(".##########");
    fmt.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);

    // warm up
    fmt.format(pi);

    long mme = -(getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes() - getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes());
    long memu1 = getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes();

    String val = fmt.format(pi);

    long memu2 = getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes();

    System.out.println(val);
    System.out.println("Format + string mem usage: " + (memu2 - memu1 - mme));

}

@Test
public void testFormatter() {
    System.out.println("\njava.util.Formatter");
    double pi = Math.PI;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
    Formatter ftm = new Formatter(sb);

    // warm up
    ftm.format("%.10f", pi);
    sb.setLength(0);

    // memory measurment error
    long mme = -(getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes() - getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes());

    long memu0 = getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes();

    ftm.format("%.10f", pi);

    long memu1 = getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes();

    String val = sb.toString();

    long memu2 = getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes();

    System.out.println(val);
    System.out.println("Format mem usage: " + (memu1 - memu0 - mme));
    System.out.println("Format + string mem usage: " + (memu2 - memu0 - 2 * mme));

}

@Test
public void testStringFormat() {
    System.out.println("\njava.lang.String.format()");

    double pi = Math.PI;

    // warmup
    String.format("%.10f", pi);

    // memory measurment error
    long mme = -(getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes() - getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes());

    long memu1 = getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes();

    String val = String.format("%.10f", pi);

    long memu2 = getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes();

    System.out.println(val);
    System.out.println("Format + string mem usage: " + (memu2 - memu1 - mme));

}

@Test
public void testDoubleFormatUtil() {
    System.out.println("\norg.apache.xmlgraphics.util.DoubleFormatUtil.formatDouble()");

    double pi = Math.PI;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(64);

    // warmup
    DoubleFormatUtil.formatDouble(pi, 10, 10, sb);
    sb.setLength(0);

    // memory measurment error
    long mme = -(getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes() - getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes());

    long memu0 = getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes();

    DoubleFormatUtil.formatDouble(pi, 10, 10, sb); 

    long memu1 = getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes();

    String val = sb.toString();

    long memu2 = getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes();

    System.out.println(val);
    System.out.println("Format mem usage: " + (memu1 - memu0 - mme));
    System.out.println("Format + string mem usage: " + (memu2 - memu0 - 2 * mme));

}


private long getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes() {
    return ((com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean)ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean()).getThreadAllocatedBytes(Thread.currentThread().getId());
}
```